# How do I fix the problem with the capitalization checker?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a one problem. This my TodoList Project: https://codepen.io/BerkayAkgurgen/pen/OJRqjPg (Please Check The Link İf you want to better understand the problem.) I'm trying to prevent the same words from being added to the list as items. I'm trying to control it with the "toLowerCase" command inside. But it keeps adding the same words because their letter sizes are different, for example: "Berkay" "berkay" I want these two words not to be included even if their letter sizes are different.

```
 function addTodo(e) {
    const newTodoValue = todoInput.value.trim();
    const newTodoValuee = todoInput.value.trim().toLowerCase();
    let todos = getTodosFromStorage();
    if (newTodoValue === "") {
        console.log("merhaba");
    } else if (todos.includes(newTodoValuee)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Aynı Todo");
        todoInput.value = "";
        return false;
    } else {
        addTodoToUI(newTodoValue);
        addTodoToStorage(newTodoValue);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `todos.includes(newTodoValuee)` requires to be extended since your case is different.

Instead use this: `if(todos.some(a=>a.trim().toLowerCase() == newTodoValuee))`

Comment: Thanks for your solve but I have a one question. ı am new in JavaScript. What does mean "=>"?

Comment: That's a whole different question. check this out: [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). If your question is answered, mark the response as answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are checking for lowercase but you are not converting the words in your array to lowercase before hand.

```
//Functions

function addTodo(e) {
    const newTodoValue = todoInput.value.trim();
    const lowerCaseTodoValue = todoInput.value.trim().toLowerCase();
    let todos = getTodosFromStorage();

  //should now convert to lowercase use this for comparisons
  var words = todos.map(w => w.toLowerCase());
  
  
    if (newTodoValue === "") {
        console.log("merhaba");
    } else if (words.includes(lowerCaseTodoValue)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Aynı Todo");
        todoInput.value = "";
        return false;
    } else {
        addTodoToUI(newTodoValue);
        addTodoToStorage(newTodoValue);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

This should resolve your issue

Comment: Thanks for your solve but I have a one question. ı am new in JavaScript. What does mean "=>"?

Comment: Converting all the items to lowercase every time an item is added, is a waste of resources. Use `.some` for doing this as less as possible.

Comment: It is in a sense short hand. Now instead of having to do function addTodo(e) {blah blah blah} you could do addTodo = (e) => {blah blah blah). If you would like to learn a little more take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp. Highly recommend taking a look at w3 schools documentation if you are new to js/css/or html

Comment: I do agree with Som, the '.some()' is a very handy thing to use. My method adds more execution time because now it has to loop through the elements, then store them to a variable, then continue with the function.  By using the '.some()' method you are able to reduce all this wasted time and resources. If you are confused on the '.some()' method take a quick look at https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-some-and-find-f9fb9826ddfd

Comment: Or take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions, Mozilla Docs are also a very good resource to look into if you are learning web development

Answer (score -1):

**The todo you converted to lower case is not the one you added to your todo list**

- You converted your todo to lowercase with variable **newTodoValuee**
- You saved something different **newTodoValue**

**Note the double "e" at the end of each variable**

This means that the lowercase todo you're checking for in your todo list is never there except it was saved as lowercase

**Simply change the variable**

```
function addTodo(e) {
    const newTodoValue = todoInput.value.trim();
    const newTodoValuee = todoInput.value.trim().toLowerCase();
    let todos = getTodosFromStorage();
    if (newTodoValue === "") {
        console.log("merhaba");
    } else if (todos.includes(newTodoValuee)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Aynı Todo");
        todoInput.value = "";
        return false;
    } else {
        addTodoToUI(newTodoValue);
        // addTodoToStorage(newTodoValue);  //change the variable here to the one that end with "ee"
       addTodoToStorage(newTodoValuee);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Then you will lose the User's Capitalization in the string.

Comment: Then, in that case the only thing I can think of is to use `findIndex`, which I believe would still perform when the data is large

Comment: See the accepted answer. JS offers `some` which is very useful in this case.